# Луковичні чи цибулинні рослини?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів

Один з дописів на сайті садового центру:

*"Багато наших покупців хочуть придбати **луковиці** зараз, не знаючи про те, що висаджуються вони восени (**луковичні** рослини повинні вкорінитися та пройти випробування холодом). Деякі садівники, лише пробують себе в квітникарстві і тому, не можуть цього знати. Отже, якщо ви не встигли, з будь-яких причин, висадити весняні першоцвіти, з квітня місяця - тюльпани, крокуси, гіацинти, нарциси будуть в контейнері в нашому садовому центрі."*

***Чи є правильним (усталеним) вживати луковичні рослини?***

У [Російсько-українському академічному словнику](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) наводиться переклад:

> Лу́ковичный – цибули́нний, цибу́льний, цибу́ляний.  • -ные растения –
> **цибу́льні росли́ни.**

Також у СУМ наведені такі визначення:

> **[ЦИБУЛИНА](http://sum.in.ua/s/cybulyna)** 1. Потовщена, перев. куляста частина стебла деяких рослин,
> яка складається з щільно розташованих м'ясистих листків і звичайно
> міститься в землі.
>
> **[ЛУКОВИЦЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/lukovycja)** Розширена частина деяких органів, частин організму тощо.

*Невпевнена, але думаю краще вживати **цибулинні** рослини, **луковичні** мені здається русизмом.*

Comment: А що означає взагалі «луковичні»/«цибулинні»? Це назва підродини/родини, чи це форма плоду чи що?

Comment: (Для підродини Allioideae (a.k.a. Alliaceae) Вікіпедія застосовує назву «[цибулеві](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Цибулеві)» — але наскільки вона правильна — я не знаю.)

Comment: З сучасного «Словника української мови» 2010-х років вилучили слова «[луковиця](http://sum.in.ua/s/lukovycja)» і «[луковичний](http://sum.in.ua/s/lukovychnyj)» — мабуть недарма (хоча орфографічні словники часто все ще за інерцією їх містять).

Comment: «Словники України on-line» містять такі _прикметники на цибул-_: цибуле́вий, цибули́нний, цибулиноподі́бний, цибули́стий, цибулі́вський, цибу́льківський, цибу́лькуватий, цибу́льний, цибу́льницький, цибулюва́тий, цибу́ляний, цибуля́стий, цибу́лячий — і ще _множинний іменник_ цибули́нові, — яке з них правильне, я не знаю.

Comment: @Sasha В даному випадку "луковичні"/"цибулинні" мається на увазі рослини (квіти) з видозміненим пагоном ("цибулина"/"луковиця"). Питання стосується рослин, які розмножуються вегатативно ("цибулиною"/"луковицею") "висадити весняні першоцвіти, з квітня місяця - тюльпани, крокуси, гіацинти, нарциси ".

Comment: Тоді напевно «цибулина» ([Вікіпедія 1](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пагін#Цибулина), [Вікіпедія 2](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Цибулина), [підручник 6 класу](http://www.yaklas.com.ua/p/biologiya/6/organi-kv-tkovikh-roslin-16041/pag-n-steblo-listki-brunki-16044/re-5b1d88d4-edcd-4df5-8d3d-e53786a987ea)). Вибачте, що не пишу повноцінну відповідь — нема часу. Який прикметник вжити — не знаю, але теж схиляюся до «цибулинних».

Comment: @Sasha, можу оформити ваші коментарі як community-wiki, якщо ви не проти, маю трохи часу.

Comment: @s0nata, якщо у Вас є бажання — звісно, я лише «за»!

Answer (score 1):

Вірним варіантом буде "цибулинні рослини" (згідно до [Всеукраїнської великої енциклопедії рослин](http://roslunu.com.ua/tsibulinni/)). Також [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96) дає варіант "цибулеві".